# Unable to fetch ECR docker image

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-ecr

When I am trying to pull docker image from ECR, I am getting the below error:

```
Get https://3242344.dkr.ecr.ap-south-1.amazonaws.imagename/latest: no basic auth credentials
```

Docker service is running fine and I am able to list the repositories.

Comment: Try running aws ecr get-login --region <<region>> with your specific region and then executed the command provided

Answer (score 2):

First, you need to Authenticate your Docker logins to the Amazon ECR:

```
aws ecr get-login --region <<region>> --no-include-email
```

Refer below link for Amazon ECR Registries authentication:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/Registries.html#registry_auth

Describe your image within a repository by using below command:

```
aws ecr describe-images --repository-name amazonlinux
```

Pull the image by using below command:

```
docker pull aws_account_id.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/amazonlinux:latest
```

For more information please refer below link: 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/docker-pull-ecr-image.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to retrieve the `docker login` command using AWS CLI

```bash
$(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region <your region>)
```

More info in [Getting Started with Amazon ECR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/ECR_GetStarted.html).